# Let's get critical: Jun 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Magento Stack Exchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Define pay-what-you-want products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3992/define-pay-what-you-want-products)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [How to Programmatically set a Product's Multi-Select Attribute by Labels](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3356/how-to-programmatically-set-a-products-multi-select-attribute-by-labels)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Magento - Get Products from Specific Category](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3441/magento-get-products-from-specific-category)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Moving Products from 1.4 to 1.7 - dilemma](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3944/moving-products-from-1-4-to-1-7-dilemma)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to clone the collection in Magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4010/how-to-clone-the-collection-in-magento)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Changing the address book drop down (for shipping) from drop down list to radio buttons](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4012/changing-the-address-book-drop-down-for-shipping-from-drop-down-list-to-radio)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Invalid product ID throws PHP error in CMS](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4095/invalid-product-id-throws-php-error-in-cms)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Improving error messages for XML compilation errors](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4111/improving-error-messages-for-xml-compilation-errors)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Add Input Validation to Product Attribute with MySQL Install Script](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3402/add-input-validation-to-product-attribute-with-mysql-install-script)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Google CDN jQuery with Local Fallback in Magento Layout XML](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3523/google-cdn-jquery-with-local-fallback-in-magento-layout-xml)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)